# Object retain in memory when click on listview headertemplate in iOS device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio, xamarin.forms.listview

I am developing an enterprise application using Xamarin.Forms. I am facing a memory leak issue in iOS specifically (working fine in Android).

**Its regarding click over listview item header**, I implemented gestures, then a transparent button as well, but it causes a memory leak - even if I comment out its functionality.

**If I comment testbutton then its objects are disposing fine.** What can I do to fix this issue?

````
 ```
    <ListView
                    Style="{DynamicResource BaseListViewStyle}"
                    IsGroupingEnabled="True"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Deliveries.ExpandedDeliveryItemModels}"
                    IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
                    IsRefreshing="{Binding Deliveries.IsRefreshing}"
                    RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
                    SelectionMode="None">
                    <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell AutomationId="headerCell">
                                <StackLayout AutomationId="headerLayout" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label  Text="{Binding HeaderTitle}"
                                            AutomationId="DeliveriesToday"
                                            HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                    </Label>
                                    <Button x:Name="testbutton"
                                            HorizontalOptions="End"
                                            Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference deliveriesPage}, Path=BindingContext.HeaderClickCommand}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                                    </Button>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell AutomationId="deliveriesCell">
                                <Label Text="Testing"></Label>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO !

You can have a try with modifying **[CachingStrategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listviewcachingstrategy?view=xamarin-forms)** of `ListView` , there are three types of *CachingStrategy* value.

- **RecycleElement** `1` Indicates that unneeded cells will have their binding contexts updated to that of a cell that is needed.
- **RecycleElementAndDataTemplate** `3` Indicates that, in addition to the behavior specified by RecycleElement, DataTemplate objects that are selected by a DataTemplateSelector are cached by the data template type.
- **RetainElement** `0` Indicates that for every item in the List View's ItemsSource property, a single unique element will be constructed from the DataTemplate.

The deflault value is `RetainElement`, the behavior is to retain item data in their generated cells when they are not needed.

For performance reasons, it is likely that the default behavior will be changed to **RecycleElement** in a future release. In the meantime, for memory and performance reasons, app developers should specify **RecycleElement** when constructing a new List View.

Therefore , you can modify code as follow :

```
<ListView CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <!-- ... -->
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: @Rvkamboj Okey , could you share a sample project link here ? I will check that .

Comment: @Rvkamboj In addition, could you share a `.gif` to explain about this *If I comment testbutton then its objects are disposing fine.* ? Becasue not too much understanding about this . This will be helpful to reproduce this in my loacl site .